# Django pythot Module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я делаю сайт на django. И когда я пытаюсь запустить сервер у меня выдает ошибку:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 42, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 61, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, "url_patterns", [])
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 738, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 731, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 39, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'articles'
```

Но вроде бы у меня все правильно в settings.py:

```
import os, sys
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# python manage.py makemigrations articles


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'grappelli',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    "article.apps.ArticleConfig"

]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoProject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoProject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Это вот корневой urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

# Serializers define the API representation.
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff']

# ViewSets define the view behavior.
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

И я реально искал на всяких форумах, исправлял что там было написано. Ошибка не изменилась.
Честно, я не знаю где ошибка. Если еще что то надо, я добавлю.

Comment: А существует файл articles/articles.py?

Comment: нет, но раньше и без него запускалось

Comment: Значит раньше не добавляли его в url.py. Чтобы работало - добавьте все отсутствующие модули, упоминающиеся в urlpatterns.

Comment: Именно в корневой? Или в урл привязку приложения?

Comment: В urlpatterns в urls.py у вас прописан импорт модулей, которых у вас фактически нет, из-за этого возникает ошибка "модуль не найден". Чтобы ошибки не было — нужно либо добавить нужные модули, либо убрать импорты, если они вдруг на самом деле не нужны (ну мало ли, такое тоже может быть).

Comment: Я с django не разбирался, наверное нужен все-таки файл articles/urls.py (видимо это в данном случае означает `include('articles.urls')`)

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую. И это да он есть в article. Я тоже не очень разбираюсь в Django. Поэтому и спрашиваю. Просто я это взял с прошлого проекта (он у меня слетел из за pip) и там у меня такой ошибки не было